# How to find Voltage based on reference nodes?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage

[image]

Here, $V_{ab}$ indicates the voltage referenced from node $b$ to node $a$. In other words, imagine $V_{ab}$ being identified in the diagram as having a "$-$" at node $b$ and a "$+$" at node $a$. The other voltages are specified using the labeled references.

Can anyone explain how to solve these questions? I have tried very hard, but I am still confused about how to do them.

Question 1) Find the value of $V_C$ in volts

Question 2) For the same circuit, find $V_{ac}$ in units of Volts. Again, this voltage reference is from node $c$ to node $a$.

Question 3) For the same circuit, find $V_F$ in units of volts.

Comment: Please note that homework type questions are considered off-topic. If you have a conceptual problem that is stopping you from solving it, then please post that conceptual question instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a KVL problem, because of the Conservation of Energy, the sum of voltages in a loop must add up to 0, since if a charge were to go around the entire loop it comes back to the same point, which means it must have the same energy.

I'll solve one as an example, the rest you can do with the same principle.

Start at node $a$, with potential $v_A$, lose potential $V_A$, lose potential $V_C$, gain potential $V_E$, lose potential $V_G$; our resultant potential is now $V_b$ since we are at node $b$. This path as an equation is:

$$V_a-V_A-V_C+V_E-V_G=V_b$$
$$(V_a-V_b)-V_A+V_E-V_G=V_C$$
$$V_C=(1-3+2-2)\text{V}=-2\text{V}$$

Basically find a path wherein you only have one unknown voltage and solve. For more complex networks you might have to find 2 paths each with 2 unknowns and solve the system of equations. Wont be required here.